# Assetic and my assets

Tags: symfony, sass, assetic

I'm new in symfony 2 and Assetic. I'd like use assetic and Sass for my CSS. I use Custom Fonts. I create in my bundle under Resources the folder "assets/css" and inside I have _base.scss and main.scss. In my public folder I have:

- css
- fonts
- images
- js

In fonts I have my custom fonts.

In my SCSS I retrive my fonts and my images like this:

```
    @include font-face("billabongregular", font-files("/bundles/Mybundle/fonts/billabong-webfont.ttf"));
background: $bg_header url("/bundles/Mybundle/images/darkGreyBackground.jpg") fixed no-repeat top center;
```

I have this path after assets:install, and I have my file under web/mybundle/fonts and web/mybundle/images

When I do `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`

I have in my web:

- css
- js (folder in public)

But I haven't Fonts folder and images folders. If IO see the source code in images I have this path /bundles/Mybundle/images/darkGreyBackground.jpg

Why I haven't all folder in web? Is it right call my images and my fonts with /bundles/Mybundle/images/darkGreyBackground.jpg and /bundles/Mybundle/fonts/billabong-webfont.ttf?

Comment: Please stop editing your question to restore the horrible broken grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard and expected behavior to have the symbolic links of the resources of your bundle being under `web/bundles/Mybundle/` after you call the `php app/console assetic:dump` command.

To use the assets generated path in your css, you can use the `cssrewrite` filter or even more simple, your `css` and `images` folders being in the same main folder, use relative path:

```
@include font-face("billabongregular", font-files("../fonts/billabong-webfont.ttf"));
background: $bg_header url("../images/darkGreyBackground.jpg") fixed no-repeat top center;
```

**EDIT**

In your bundle, if you want a file to be accessible in the `web` directory after your run the `assets:install` command, you have to put them inside the `Resources/public/` directory as stated here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html#bundle-directory-structure

Comment: Thanks.. if i use background: $bg_header url("../images/darkGreyBackground.jpg") fixed no-repeat top center;
the image is searched in web/images but I do not have this folder.
if i use cssrewrite i have this path /Resources/assets/images..

Comment: for now i use bundles/mybundle/images/darkGreyBackground.jpg without using the filter cssrewrite. but if I'm going to see the html page generated in the code I see paths like /bundles/mybundle/myimage do not think this is correct as to show

Comment: But do you have this css code inside a css file in the resources of your bundle or directly in your `web/css` directory?

Comment: i have scss inside Acme/MyBundle/Resources/assets/css/scss Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I just tried using the following as a workaround. Seems to work so far.

```
{% stylesheets
    output='assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf'
    'bundles/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf'
%}{% endstylesheets %}
```

Notice the omission of any output which means nothing shows up on the template. When I run assetic:dump the files are copied over to the desired location and the css includes work as expected.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted but this workaround works when you don't have access to the source files or just don't want to modify them.

Comment: In my experience this causes the font to be transferred with the wrong MIME type, as least in chrome you get: `Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html`

Comment: @FrankvanLuijn That is an issue with your .htaccess/apache.conf You should be configured to serve the files directly without the routes going through the Symfony app.php